# Change Content In Another Div Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to change content of another div (`id="new-text"`) by clicking on a link container and using a JavaScript function (`show-text()`)

```html
    <section>
        <div class="row">               
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <a href="#" id="text-1" onclick="show-text()">
            <div class="home-side-menu">Mission Statement</div></a>
            <a href="#" id="text-2" onclick="show-text()">
            <div class="home-side-menu">Letter-writing</div></a>
            <a href="#" id="text-3" onclick="show-text()">
            <div class="home-side-menu">Peace Ideas</div></a>
            <a href="#" id="text-4" onclick="show-text()">
            <div class="home-side-menu">Power Of Love</div></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
            <div class="text-formatting" id="new-text">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show-text(id){
            if id="text-1"
            document.getElementById('new-text').innerHTML="SAMPLE TEXT 1"
            if id="text-2"
            document.getElementById('new-text').innerHTML="SAMPLE TEXT 2"
            if id="text-3"
            document.getElementById('new-text').innerHTML="SAMPLE TEXT 3"
            if id="text-4"
            document.getElementById('new-text').innerHTML="SAMPLE TEXT 4"           
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: A function name can't contain characters like hyphens; instead use a [camelCase name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Writing_guidelines/Writing_style_guide/Code_style_guide/JavaScript#function_names). On the other hand, an `if` condition should have been inside parenthesis, and if you want to compare two different values, use the [equality operator (==)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality).

Comment: For one, your HTML is not valid. And, why are you yelling at us? PLEASE DON'T TYPE IN ALL CAPS. It's considered as yelling and it is rude.

Answer (score 0):

The Changed Code(Working)

```html
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <a href="#" id="text-1" onclick="showText('text-1')">
                <div class="home-side-menu">Mission Statement</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" id="text-2" onclick="showText('text-2')">
                <div class="home-side-menu">Letter-writing</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" id="text-3" onclick="showText('text-3')">
                <div class="home-side-menu">Peace Ideas</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" id="text-4" onclick="showText('text-4')">
                <div class="home-side-menu">Power Of Love</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
            <div class="text-formatting" id="new-text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showText(id) {
        if (id === "text-1")
            document.getElementById('new-text').innerHTML = "SAMPLE TEXT 1";
        if (id === "text-2")
            document.getElementById('new-text').innerHTML = "SAMPLE TEXT 2";
        if (id === "text-3")
            document.getElementById('new-text').innerHTML = "SAMPLE TEXT 3";
        if (id === "text-4")
            document.getElementById('new-text').innerHTML = "SAMPLE TEXT 4";
    }
</script>
```

Inside   `onclick="show-text()` ,pass valid arguments ( that matches with your IF conditions) like 'text-1' or 'text-2'..

It should be  `<a href="#" id="text-1" onclick="show-text('text-1')">`
and same follows rest of them.

and use `===` (Strict Equality Check) inside Script , for comparison. Check this for [Js Comparison Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Comment: Inline event attributes, such as `onclick` shouldn't event be used in the first place. Also, please don't link to your answer's code on 3rd party sites as those links can die over time, making your answer here meaningless. Just include your code inside of a Stack Snippet, right here in your answer. Also, using `===` instead of `==` is considered a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid HTML and JavaScript, so those errors must be corrected first.

See comments inline for details.

```css
/* CSS to make the clickable <div>'s look like hyperlinks */
.home-side-menu {
  color:#00f;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.home-side-menu:hover {
  color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
      <!-- Don't use <a> elements as a way to hook into a click event.
           Hyperlinks are for navigation. Just about all visual elements
           on a web page support a click event, so here just set the 
           div elements that have the right class to have a click event. -->
      <div id="text-1" class="home-side-menu">Mission Statement</div>
      <div id="text-2" class="home-side-menu">Letter-writing</div>
      <div id="text-3" class="home-side-menu">Peace Ideas</div>
      <div id="text-4" class="home-side-menu">Power Of Love</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
    <div class="text-formatting" id="new-text"></div>
  </div>
</section>


<!-- type="text/javascript" hasn't been needed in years. That's the default. -->
<script>
  // Get your DOM references just once:
  const destination = document.getElementById('new-text');
  
  // And set up your event handlers in JavaScript, not with inline HTML attributes
  // Here, we'll set the handler on a common ancestor of all the elements that when
  // clicked should call the same handler. When one is clicked, the event will bubble
  // up to the ancestor.
  document.querySelector(".row").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    // Is this an element we care to handle?
    if(event.target.classList.contains("home-side-menu")){
      showText(event.target.id);
    }
  });

  // You can't use - in a JavaScript identifier
  function showText(id){
    // In JavaScript = means assignment. == or === is for comparison
    // Also, if statement conditions must be within parenthesis
    let output = "";
    if(id === "text-1") {
      output = "SAMPLE TEXT 1";
    } else if(id === "text-2") {
      output = "SAMPLE TEXT 2";
    } else if(id ==="text-3") {
      output = "SAMPLE TEXT 3";
    } else if(id === "text-4") {
      output = "SAMPLE TEXT 4";
    }
    
    // Don't use .innerHTML when the string doesn't contain any HTML as
    // .innerHTML has security and performance implications. Use .textContent instead
    destination.textContent = output;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: MANY THANKS - BUT HOW DO I INCLUDE CSS / HTML FORMATTING IN THE OUTPUT SUCH AS <p> <div> etc

Comment: @PaulArmstrong within the `head` element, add a `<style></style>` element and place the CSS from my answer within those tags. Also, you are welcome, but please don't type in all caps as it is considered shouting and a bit rude.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this isn't considered plagiarism - I found the code on your site but I have forgotten the contributor - I modified the code to fit my website - Basically I click on a link in a side menu and it changes the content in another div - with all the formatting

tags  etc. Many thanks to someone else!!!

```
.home-side-menu {
width: 100%;
color: white;
background-color: #fcba03;
height: 50px;
opacity: 0.65;
padding: 14px;
font-size: 14px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
}

blockquote.quote {
margin-left: 15px;
border-left: 5px solid #000000;
padding-left: 10px;
color: pink;
font-size: 15px;
}

h3 {
font-size: 22px;
}

.text-formatting {
background-color: #807f7d;
margin-bottom: 10px;
opacity: 0.75;
height: auto;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 15px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.5;
}




<section>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<div class="home-side-menu text1">
    <span class="main-text text1" data-content="text1- 
    content">Mission 
    Statement</span>
    </div>
    <div class="home-side-menu text1">
    <span class="main-text text2" data-content="text2- 
    content">Letter-writing</span>
    </div>
    <div class="home-side-menu text1">
    <span class="main-text text3" data-content="text3- 
    content">Peace Ideas</span>
    </div>
    <div class="home-side-menu text1">
    <span class="main-text text4" data-content="text4- 
    content">Power Of Love</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 col-xl-9"> 
<div class="content text1-content text-formatting" 
style="display: block;">

    <h3>Mission Statement</h3>
    <p>mission statement - mission statement mission 
    statement</p>                     
    <blockquote class="quote">quote quote quote quote 
    <br/>Richard Larson
    </blockquote>
    <p>Be idealistic<br/>be idealistic be idealistic
    </p>

</div>
<div class="content text2-content text-formatting" 
style="display: none;">
    <h3>Letter Writing</h3>
    <p>letter writing letter writing letter writing<br></p>
</div>
<div class="content text3-content text-formatting" 
style="display: 
none;">
    <h3>peace ideas</h3>
    <p>peace ideas peace ideas peace ideas<br></p>
</div>
<div class="content text4-content text-formatting" 
style="display: none;">
    <h3>power of love</h3>
    <p>power of love power of love power of love<br></p>
</div>


</div>
</div>
</section>    

<script>
    $('.main-text').click(function(event){
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.text1').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $('.' + $(this).data('content')).slideDown();
    event.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: *I found the code on your site* <-- You found the code on who's site?

Comment: Apologies - I am a newbie to stackoverflow [I registered years ago but never usee the site until now. I did some searching via [History] Desas is the name of the person who provided the correct example that I used. Am I allowed provide the weblink???

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).